# Make checkbox selectable only if count is under a specific value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have trouble figuring out a problem.
I wrote my problem down in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bird-cs5uj. So I have for example two checkboxes and a count variable. The count can be increased with the +-button. If the count has reached a specific value, for example 5 the checkbox b shouldn't be selectable anymore. Do you have an idea what could solve this problem. I still want to show the checkbox so it's not an option to make the checkbox disappear at the value 5.
Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy just use `disabled` prop

```
<input
     type="checkbox"
     id="0"
     disabled={currentAmount>10} //put your condition here 
     onClick={(e) => {
          updateCheckbox(e.target.id, e.target.checked);
     }}
 />
```

Comment: Well thats to easy haha. Thank you!

Comment: I will do it as soon as it's available